# how to using codes to send different events

Tags: cocoa

I used the codes below to send event

```
[myButton setAction:@selector(eventButton:)];
```

It lookes like only for mouse click.

but how to send event for 'double click' and 'key press'?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons don't respond to double-clicks or keypresses. (A button considers a double-click to be simply two clicks.)

You need to [implement a custom view](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978) and implement the relevant [responder](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder) methods in that view's class.

You *could* make a button double-clickable, but nobody will think to try that. Discoverability is an important factor; even if you have a valid use case for your button to be double-clickable, if no-one will try it, it is of no value.

On the matter of keypresses, you should also watch the [WWDC 2010 video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) for session #145. (You can do this even if you didn't go to WWDC 2010—you just need to log into your ADC account.)